# Is there a way to gradually migrate to Svelte?

Tags: svelte

Help me to release the parking brake :)

I have several apps builded in the classic way when backend generated HTML and user interaction added with jQuery and plain JS. Now I want to migrate to Svelte.

I planned to rewrite the logic into components and add this as custom elements one by one but I have not found the way to stylize custom element by external styles. As far as I understand this limitation is due to the use of the Shadow DOM so that styles don't leak into other components.

OK, it's reasonably but there is a way to gradually migrate to Svelte without extracting for each component but uses external styles from legacy build?

Comment: Components-scoped CSS is an extra. Nothing prevents you from attaching an external global stylesheet the way you would do it within a conventional website/app (via `<link rel="stylesheet">` inside the entry point html, via JS, or via the `<svelte:head>` helper),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can gradually migrate components by import it into your old school layout. For this to work you need to start migrate your javascript into a module styled fashion otherwise you cannot import.

```html
# svelte/public/index.html
<head>
    <script type="module" src="old-school-js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- Svelte main.js -->
    <script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chat"></div>
<div id="old-school"></div>
...
```

```js
# Svelte main.js
import Chat from './Chat.svelte';
new Chat({
    target: document.querySelector('#chat'),
});
```

Adding existing CSS could be reused maybe by using [`svelte-add`](https://github.com/svelte-add/svelte-add) adding SCSS support so you can used variables into your components.